# Search for whole words in Monodevelop IDE

Tags: monodevelop, replace

This is driving me crazy.  Various pages mention flags for whole-word search but I can't find 'em.  Running MonoDevelop 2.4 in Ubuntu.  So far I can only do simple text searches, so searching for "Sit" results in "SitAction" etc.  I want to find just the cases where "Sit" is bounded by white space or the boundary of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would strongly recommend upgrading MD, ideally to the current release (3.0.3.1 at time of writing). MonoDevelop 2.4 is very old.

If you use incremental search, the option is in a dropdown menu when you click on the magnifying glass:

[image: The Whole Words Only option in incremental search]

If you use Find in Files, the checkbox is right there in the dialog:

[image: The Whole Words Only option in Find in Files]